# Ubuntu 20.10 Totem h264 bug

Tags: bug-reporting, totem, h264

I was able to play anything with MKV player but when it comes to  gnome (Totem by its old name) I've faced with H.264 error constantly. I have tried restricted extras, reinstalls anything that experienced linux users guided internet. It didn't helped me at all. I became obsessed with this and decided to figure it out without formatting whole system.

Today I tried these with terminal,

```
 1019  sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav
 1020  sudo apt-get install libavcodec58
 1021  sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread8
 1022  sudo apt install libdvread8
 1023  sudo apt install libdvdread8
 1024  sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav ffmpeg
 1025  sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
 1026  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
 1028  rm -R ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0
 1029  history
```

while most of them was tried-before solutions deleting gstreamers cache and libavcodec58 and libdvdread 8 was a solution somehow. I am not an ubuntu expert nor linux. But after installing 20.04 this issue was annoying me and saw some of the people are also having this issue with their computers, so I wanted to share the solution.

Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  We use a Q&A format here. If you would like to share a solution to a problem, please make sure that you use the *question* to describe your problem. Then you can post an *answer* below with your solution.  You can also come back in a few days and "accept" your own answer to let the community know that this question/problem has a solution.  Note, however, that bug reports are off topic. They aren't triaged here so if you would like to report a bug, please use the official bug reporting channels.  https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: In addition to what Nmath said, if by "and saw some of the people are also having this issue with their computers" you mean people here on Ask Ubuntu, I'm sure they would appreciate if you were to post it as an answer under their question.